# Sending messages with delay

Tags: chatbot, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-chatbot

I'm implementing a Facebook Messenger Chatbot, and in one of the conversation flows, the bot is supposed to send 6 messages, one after the other.

I'd like those messages to be delayed by 1 second, and between them, display a sender action, to make the conversation feel natural (vs. dumping 6 messages all at once, which forces the user to scroll up to read them all).

I tried 2 different webhook implementations, but neither of them work. One was in **Python/Flask**: between each message, I've put `time.sleep(delay)`, but it didn't work. The other was in **Javascript/NodeJS**: between each message, I've put `setTimeout(function() {sendMessage(recipient_id);}, delay)`, but it also didn't work. Both versions work perfectly without the delay.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code, it waits for 1 second and then replies back using async/await.

```
const messages = ["first", "second", "third", "forth", "fifth", "sixth"];

const sleep = delay => {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(resolve, delay);
  });
};

const displayMessage = async messages => {
  for (let message of messages) {
    await sleep(1 * 1000);
    console.log(message);
  }
};

displayMessage(messages);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use settimeout for such scenarios. But for showing sender_action let's say if you want to show text like `typing...` from the bot inside messenger then facebook provides functionalities in its messenger API to include sender actions with different tags. Here is how I am doing it.

```
sender_action: 'typing...',
messaging_type: 'MESSAGE_TAG',
tag: 'NON_PROMOTIONAL_SUBSCRIPTION',
```

Please look into the following link for more information.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/sender-actions

Answer (score 0):

It'd be better if you provide more code when asking the question. I have the suspicion that you actually do this:

```
setTimeout(function() {sendMessage(recipient_id);}, delay)
setTimeout(function() {sendMessage(recipient_id);}, delay)
setTimeout(function() {sendMessage(recipient_id);}, delay)
setTimeout(function() {sendMessage(recipient_id);}, delay)
setTimeout(function() {sendMessage(recipient_id);}, delay)
setTimeout(function() {sendMessage(recipient_id);}, delay)
```

`setTimeout` is asynchronous, it means that your code will wait 1 second and then send 6 messages in a row. You're probably looking for something like this:

```
await setTimeout(function() {sendMessage(recipient_id);}, delay)
await setTimeout(function() {sendMessage(recipient_id);}, delay)
await setTimeout(function() {sendMessage(recipient_id);}, delay)
await setTimeout(function() {sendMessage(recipient_id);}, delay)
await setTimeout(function() {sendMessage(recipient_id);}, delay)
await setTimeout(function() {sendMessage(recipient_id);}, delay)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check out the [wingbot](https://wingbot.ai) library [here on the github](https://github.com/wingbotai/wingbot). It helps with building a simple bot. Like this:

```js
const { Router } = require('wingbot');

const bot = new Router();

bot.use('start', (req, res) => {
   res.typingOn()
      .wait(1000)
      .text('Hello');
});
```